# Javascript: Limit how quickly a keydown event listener can call a function when held down

Tags: javascript, canvas, event-handling

I'm working on a JavaScript based game and I am currently working on game character movement and animation. This is controlled when the player presses the controls (WASD) during the `keydown` event. The problem I have is that the handler is called too quickly when these keys are pressed and held down, which makes my game character/sprite look like he's having a seizure (because it is cycling through the sprite images too quickly).

How can I limit the speed that calls to the character movement/animation behaviour are made? My code currently looks like this:

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let xPos = 10
let yPos = 10
document.addEventListener('keydown', movement)

function movement(e){
//Player Controls 
// horizontal and vertical movement
    if (e.keyCode === 87 ){
         ctx.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
         y=y-3;
         sY = 97
         runningMan();
    }
     if(e.keyCode === 83){
        ctx.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        y=y+3;
        sY = 0
        runningMan();
    }
    if(e.keyCode === 65){
        ctx.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        x=x-3;
        sY = 32
        runningMan();
    }
    if(e.keyCode === 68){
        ctx.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        x=x+3;
        sY = 64
        runningMan();
    }
  
 
    // keeping the player inside the canvas
    xPos = Math.min(Math.max(x, 0+5), canvas.width-10);
    yPos = Math.min(Math.max(y, 0+5), canvas.height-10); 
}

//img,SX,SY,SW,SH,DX,DY,DW,DH)
let img = new Image();
img.src = 'runningGood.png'
let cycle = 0
let sY;
let sW = 30 
let sH = 32
let x = 0
let y = 0
let increase = 0
// setInterval(runningMan, 200);
function runningMan(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,sW+increase,sH+increase);
    ctx.drawImage(img,cycle*sW,sY,sW,sH,x,y,70,70)
    cycle = (cycle + 1) % 3;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang='en'>
        <head>
            <meta charset='UTF-8'>
            <script src='project.js' defer></script>
            <title>1045 Project</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <canvas id='myCanvas' width='750' height ='750' style='border: 2px solid black'></canvas>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: plenty of scripts out there for throttling/debouncing calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution that integrates with your current code, and avoids the need for a third party library would be to add the following:

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let xPos = 10
let yPos = 10

/* Add: track state of current throttle timer */
let throttle;
/* Add: When keyup happens, just reset the throttle timer */
document.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
  if (throttle) {
    clearTimeout(throttle);
    throttle = null;
  }
})

document.addEventListener('keydown', movement)

function movement(e) {

  /* Add: only allow normal keypress processing if no throttle
  timer is currently active */
  if (!throttle) {

    //Player Controls 
    // horizontal and vertical movement
    if (e.keyCode === 87) {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      y = y - 3;
      sY = 97
      runningMan();
    }
    if (e.keyCode === 83) {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      y = y + 3;
      sY = 0
      runningMan();
    }
    if (e.keyCode === 65) {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      x = x - 3;
      sY = 32
      runningMan();
    }
    if (e.keyCode === 68) {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      x = x + 3;
      sY = 64
      runningMan();
    }


    // keeping the player inside the canvas
    xPos = Math.min(Math.max(x, 0 + 5), canvas.width - 10);
    yPos = Math.min(Math.max(y, 0 + 5), canvas.height - 10);


    /* Add: Start a "throttle" timer that prevents next keyboard processing
    until timer completed */
    throttle = setTimeout(() => {

      throttle = null;

    /* Your throttle interval - reduce/increase this number to suit you needs */
    }, 1000)
  }
}

//img,SX,SY,SW,SH,DX,DY,DW,DH)
let img = new Image();
img.src = 'https://via.placeholder.com/160'
let cycle = 0
let sY;
let sW = 30
let sH = 32
let x = 0
let y = 0
let increase = 0
// setInterval(runningMan, 200);
function runningMan() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, sW + increase, sH + increase);
  ctx.drawImage(img, cycle * sW, sY, sW, sH, x, y, 70, 70)
  cycle = (cycle + 1) % 3;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>

<head>
  <meta charset='UTF-8'>
  <script src='project.js' defer></script>
  <title>1045 Project</title>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id='myCanvas' width='750' height='750' style='border: 2px solid black'></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

The general idea here is to start a `throttle` timer after regular `keydown` processing occurs. The `throttle` timer basically blocks/prevents the same `keydown` processing (ie game character movement) from occurring immediatly in the next iteration of your app/event loop (which is the cause for the erratic motion of the game character).

Hope this helps!